# Alternative to .gitattributes

Tags: git, git-merge, gitattributes

I've been searching for a way to merge a branch into another without overriding image & css folders. I looked up around SO and found some questions and answers mentioning .gitattribute.

I also checked out the official documentation.

But I must be missing something, because every time I try to do a merge (between two branches where I have replaced images) I get a merge conflict.

For reference, this is my .gitattributes file, included in both branches:

```
/res/icon/                 merge=ours
/res/screen/               merge=ours
/platforms/                merge=ours
/www/assets/css/           merge=ours
/www/background_splash.png merge=ours
/www/bglogin.png           merge=ours
/www/top_bar.png           merge=ours
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Also, is there another option for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all files within `res/icon`, you need either:

```
/res/icon/*                merge=ours
```

(if there are no subdirectories) or:

```
/res/icon/**/*             merge=ours
```

(if there are subdirectories).  Repeat this pattern for all directories.

But note that there is a flaw: the `ours` merge driver will *only be used if there is something to combine*.  That is, suppose there a file named `res/icon/foo.img`.  In the *merge base* commit, this is an image of the letter B for Base.  In *your* branch, this is still an image of the letter B, bit-for-bit identical to the original file.  In *their* branch, this is a different image, or a different color, or whatever, so that the file is not bit-for-bit identical.

Running `git merge theirs`, your Git will compare the base B in `res/icon/foo.img` to your B, see that they are the same, compare the base B to their image, see that they are different, and *choose their file* because there is nothing to resolve.

If you *did* change the file in any way, Git compares the base `res/icon/foo.img` B to your `res/icon/foo.img` file (maybe your B is now a different color).  Git compares the base B to their file.  Both you and they have changes, so there are different changes to combine.  Now Git will use your `merge=ours` driver to achieve the combining.

(Git probably should have a flag, "merge driver must always be used" or some such, to *force* it to use your driver even if Git thinks there are no changes to combine.  But Git does not have such a flag today.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. If I may add, you have to use it like this ```git merge -X theirs <branch_name>```.

Comment: `-X theirs` just means that where there is no specified driver, so that Git uses its own internal merge driver, the internal merge driver should resolve conflicts by choosing their change. Usually you would want `-X ours` if you are using `merge=ours`...